# Why bind function is returning -1

Tags: c, sockets

So i am following the book of UNIX network programming, and tried to write a simple daytime server from chapter 1 and client but the bind function is always returning an error, what I'm doing wrong can anyone help??

#### server.c

```c
/*
 * Daytime Server
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void printError(char *str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[4096];
    time_t ticks;

    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printError("Error at line 32 socket fuct.");
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        printError("Error at bind function");
    }
    

    if (listen(listenfd, 1024) < 0)
    {
        printError("Error at listen fuct.");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            printError("Error at accept fuct.");
        }

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));

        if (write(connfd, buff, strlen(buff)) < 0)
        {
            printError("Error at write fuct.");
        }

        close(connfd);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### client.c

```c
/*
 * Daytime Client
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void printError(char *str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int socketfd, n;
    char recvline[4097];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printError("Requires ip address of the server");
    }

    if ((socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printError("Unable to create a Connection");
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printError("Not valid IP");
    }

    if (connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        printError("Connection Error");
    }

    while ((n = read(socketfd, recvline, 4096)) > 0)
    {
        recvline[n] = 0;
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            printError("Fputs Error");
        }
    }

    if (n < 0)
    {
        printError("Not readable");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running server is always returning -1 on bind function. and running client always prints `connection error`.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Port numbers below 1024 usually require root privilege.  Try >= 1024.

Comment: Thanks Both for help, and yep putting `perror` prints `Permission denied` in the console, so either changing port to >1024 or running with `sudo` is working.

Comment: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a good (up to date) reference for basic networking. `getaddrinfo()` has replaced a lot of the manual connection setup for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*`getaddrinfo()` has replaced a lot of the manual connection setup for both IPv4 and IPv6*" - while that is true, it doesn't apply to this issue, and wouldn't have made any difference.

Comment: Agreed @RemyLebeau, that's why it was noted in a comment and not made part of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check with `errno` to find out WHY `bind()` is failing when it returns -1.  You can use `perror()` to print a human-readable description of `errno` to the console, or at least `strerror()` to get that description in a string buffer that you can then do whatever you want with.

But the most likely reason for WHY `bind()` is failing is that you are trying to `bind()` your server to port 13.  On most systems, ports 0-1023 are *reserved* for system services, so you would need to run your app with admin rights to listen on those ports.